# Debuging all the code computing and sorting equivalence classes

Tags: debugging, ocaml

I have this function compute an equivalence class

```
let eq_class m i =
  let column = m.(i)
  and set = ref [] in
  Array.iteri begin fun j l ->
    if j = i || column.(j) && m.(j).(i) then
      set := j :: !set else ignore l
  end column;
  !set;;
```

and this function to collect all the classes are equivalence

```
let eq_classes m =
  let classes = ref [] in
  Array.iteri begin fun e _ ->
    if not (List.exists (List.mem e) !classes) then
      classes := eq_class m e :: !classes
  end m;
  !classes;;
```

I have this function to compare two equivalence classes:

```
let cmp_classes m c c' = if c = c' then 0 else
  match c, c' with
    | i :: _, j :: _ -> if m.(i).(j) then 1 else -1
    | _ -> assert false
```

After I used this function to sort it by using List.sort

```
let sort_eq_classes m = List.sort (cmp_classes m);;
```

My matrix is an boolean matrix, and I computed it with transitive closure.

```
let transClosure m =
  let n = Array.length m in
  for k = 0 to n - 1 do
    let mk = m.(k) in
    for i = 0 to n - 1 do
      let mi = m.(i) in
      for j = 0 to n - 1 do
    mi.(j) <- max mi.(j) (min mi.(k) mk.(j))
      done;
    done;
  done;
  m;;

let tc = transClosure matrix
let eq = eq_classes tc
let sort_eq = sort_eq_classes tc eq
```

I tested with many counter example to test all these functions, for example with the graph (matrix)

**EDIT**

matrix:

```
 a <-> b  c <-> d
 |          
 v          
 e
```

matrix_2:

```
a <-> b -> e -> f
|          |
v          v
h <------- g 
|          |
v          v  
u          k
```

I input the boolean matrix:

```
    let matrix =
   [|
   [|false; true; false; false; false|];
   [|true; false; false; false; false|];
   [|false; false; false; true; false|];
   [|false; false; true; false; false|];
   [|false; false; false; false; false|];
   |];;

let matrix_2 =
    [|
    [| false; false; false; false; false; false; false; false |];
    [| false; false; false; false; false; false; false; false |];
    [| false; false; false; true; false; false; true; false |];
    [| false; false; true; false; true; false; false; false |];
    [| true; false; false; false; false; true; false; false |];
    [| false; true; false; false; false; false; true; false |];
    [| false; false; false; false; false; false; false; true |];
    [| false; false; false; false; false; false; false; false |];
    |]
```

output of matrix 1: 
equivalence classes: `e d c b a`

sort equivalence classes: `e d c b a`

output of matrix 2:
equivalence classes: `u h g e b a k f`

sort equivalence classes : `u h k g f e b a`

And the result is correct order like I expected. But when I test it with my data, which is an xsds data, more complicated depended relations. It output for me a wrong order. I had test with function transform to boolean matrix from xsds, and tested transitive closure, it is correct. So I think may be their is some bugs in my functions, (`eq_class`) or (`cmp_classes`).

Could you please help me to see what wrong in these code?

Comment: It's extremely difficult to debug if you don't provide a short counterexample.

Comment: I edited and put an short example. Thanks

Comment: I meant an example which demonstrates wrong results from your code.

Comment: All the example I tested with these code is correct. But when I apply it to the data I support to test, it does not give me the correct order.

Comment: I checked each step in the data I'm testing, I tried with small example, and with more complicated example with I taken from the depended relations in my data (xsds tree), it's still correct. But when I test it with a whole data, it gave wrong order. And I don't know where it is wrong? is it the data supported to give this answer ? or there is a bug some where in my code?? Could you give me some ways or suggestions when to test with a big data?

Comment: Try to check the conversion from xsds trees to matrices;  it could be incorrect. Furthermore, be careful with some of your functions having side effects. When you call `let tc = transClosure matrix`, tc is just an alias to `matrix` which has been changed.

Comment: I did check the step transform from xsds to matrices, it gave me a good answer. Yes, and I also check the matrices after they do the transitive closure. It works correct. I also very careful checked again with another example. After trying many possible ways to debug, I still don't see why it is not giving a right order at the end which the whole data as an input.

Comment: Put your full code with the input demonstrating the problem to github.com or somewhere, I'll take a look.

Comment: Here is the link I uploaded [soure code](https://gforge.inria.fr/scm/viewvc.php/trunk/rainbow/devel/gwen/draft.ml?view=markup&revision=1298&root=rainbow). The input is 'entries' list, this list extracted from an xsds list, it return an output exactly when I run from xsds datatype.

Comment: How do you compare equivalence classes? When is an equivalence class the same, bigger or smaller than another equivalence class?

Comment: if two elements are in the same equivalence class they are equal (0); if they have a path from i to j then i < j (-1), otherwise i > j (1). Assumes that: each equivalence class only appears once and each equivalence class contains at least one element. (it is the function 'cmp_classes'

Comment: IN this [source code](https://gforge.inria.fr/scm/viewvc.php/trunk/rainbow/devel/gwen/draft.ml?view=markup&revision=1299&root=rainbow) I have a comment for each function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in `cmp_classes` function.

From your [source code](https://gforge.inria.fr/scm/viewvc.php/trunk/rainbow/devel/gwen/draft.ml?view=markup&revision=1299&root=rainbow):

```
(* We check that if two elements are in the same equivalence class they are
   equal (0); if they have a path from i to j then i < j (-1)
   otherwise i > j (1). We assumes that: each equivalence class only
   appears once and each equivalence class contains at least one
   element. *)

let cmp_classes m c c' = if c = c' then 0 else
  match c, c' with
    | i :: _, j :: _ -> if m.(i).(j) then 1 else -1
    | _ -> assert false
```

Obviously, your code doesn't fulfill your requirement. Several errors could be mentioned:

1. If `m.(i).(j) = true`, you don't compare between `i` and `j` at all.
2. If `m.(i).(j) = false`, you suppose to compare other combinations than `i` and `j`, but here you wrongly returns `-1`.
3. You only compare using the heads of `c` and `c'` and ignore other elements while you suppose to use any pair of elements in two lists before reaching a conclusion.

In your small examples, you got correct results because equivalence classes often have one element. Since they are collected in the order that there is no path from former ones to later ones, your returning of `-1` is fortunately correct. It's no longer the case with arbitrary input from xsd trees.

It's not difficult to fix the function if you can define it clearly. Now I still don't know the order of two equivalence classes without any path connecting them together (`{a,b}` and `{c, d}` classes in `matrix`).

In order that you can test your fix more easily, this is a small example which will produce a wrong order:

```
 a <-> b  c <-> d
 ^     ^  ^     ^
 |     |  |     |
 e     e  e     e
```

Comment: `let cmp_classes m c c' =
  match c, c' with
    | i :: _, j :: _ -> if i = j then  0 else
 if i >= j then 1 else -1
    | _ -> assert false` I tested with the example you give to me, it give a right order with this compares. I applied it to the xsds data. It still not return a right order. I tried to write a function checking with your suggestion at 1) 2) and 3),and it turn out to my function I give here.

Comment: Your new function is obviously wrong. Why do you compare them when there's maybe no path from `i` to `j` (`m.(i).(j) = false`)? Think about my suggestions; I couldn't help you more than this.

Comment: `let cmp_classes m c c' =
    match c, c' with
      | i :: _ , j :: _ ->
 if m.(i).(j) = true
 then compare i j else 
   if m.(i).(j) = false then ....
      | _ -> assert false` I don't understand about suggestion 2) support to compare another combination than i and j. I am thinking about c c', but it has not giving me a right answer.

Comment: Try to compare every element of `c` with every element of `c'` (NOT JUST COMPARING THEIR HEADS). If these elements are comparable at some point, return there. Otherwise, there is no path from an element of `c` to an element of `c'`; throw an exception.

Comment: I tried to write another function to compare i and j and tested with  a small example above, it gave me correct order but when I run it with my data, it gives the same order like before. Could you please help me?
`let cmp_classes m i j =
  if i = j then 0 else
    if m.(i).(j) then
      if m.(j).(i) then 0 else 1
    else
      if m.(j).(i) then 0 else -1`